# Get Maximum Record even if its Null

Tags: sql

I am getting Maximum transaction Record from USer Transaction table, It has a transactiontypeid which can be null, a user can have multiple transactions. My query is not returning the maximum transaction record if its null.
This is my query

```
SELECT 
    MAX([dbo].[UserTransaction].[UserTransactionId]) AS [UserTransactionId], 
    [dbo].[UserTransaction].[Userid] AS [UserId] 
FROM [dbo].[UserTransaction] 
WHERE ( [dbo].[UserTransaction].[Userid] IN (2,3))
GROUP BY [dbo].[UserTransaction].[Userid]
```

and these are my tables

```
  User Table
   UserId
   FirstName
   LastName

   UserTransaction Table
   UserTransactionId
   UserId
   TransactionTypeId
   LastModifiedDate
```

and this is the record in USerTransaction Table

```
 1    2    5    2014-09-26 02:00:21.487
 2    3   4     2014-09-26 02:00:21.487
 3    2  null   2014-09-27 02:00:21.487
 4   3  null   2014-09-27 02:00:21.487
```

It should return the records 3 and 4,but its returning the record 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on PostgreSQL 9.3 AND MS SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTransaction (
UserTransactionId int,
UserId int,
TransactionTypeId int
);
```

Simplified inserts, as we do not need date for the test, also your `User Table` is never used here.

```
INSERT INTO UserTransaction VALUES (1,2,5),(2,3,4),(3,2,null),(4,3,null);
```

Now we use

```
SELECT MAX(UserTransactionId), UserId FROM UserTransaction WHERE UserId IN (2,3) GROUP BY UserId;
```

Of course the WHERE clause can be ommitted here, and the result prints correctly:

```
 max | UserId 
-----+--------
   4 |      3
   3 |      2
```

Which is exactly what you wanted.

Here's [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e88ed/1) for you to see it for yourself.

*There is no way that a NULL column on which a query doesn't depend at all is changing your results*.

Comment: My answer has been edited after tests on MS SQL Server 2012. Please remember to state your DBMS and version in the future :)